# How do i set up an offline environment to test my Google App Engine chat room?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, offline

I'll be using the channel API, which will route the messages to a javascript client.

How do I set up the GAE SDK for this, and how do I create a javascript client that can work offline with GAE?

side note: I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: Is there some reason the default SDK deployment isn't working for you?  I've done precisely this and it has worked fine locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how to work with GAE and use its SDK?
If yes then just read the Channel API overview [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview), it has everything you need to get started.
If no then you should read the GAE getting started guide
[for python 2.5](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted)
[for python 2.7](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27)
Actually, there is no special thing that you need to set up for Channel API, it works wonderful offline, and it uses the ordinary polling mechanism for simulating the service (the real one doesn't use polling), but of course you must know how to work with the SDK.

Comment: Yes, just making sure it's possible to integrate the Javascript client with a local server. If it's all good, then thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine Tutorial on Channel API at http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise4.html. That may help.